# Adding values to a new column based on other two columns

Tags: pandas, melt

I have a data frame that looks like this. I have created 3 new columns that will take the value from other columns.I want function columns separate column and grab total hours for each user for each function.

```
 User         Function          Total hours   Damage Processing problem solve damages sweeper
 schae      Damage Processing      9.36
 Julie      Problem solve          9.70
 John       sweeper                18.9
 Dan       Damages                 1.83
 Dan       Damages                 1.83
 Julie     Damages                 1.83
 Dan       Problem solve           1.83
```

The expected output will look like

```
 User         Function          Total hours   Damage Processing  problem solve damages  sweeper
 schae     Damage Processing       9.36          9.36
 Julie     Problem solve           9.70                            9.70
 John      sweeper                 18.9                                                  18.9
 Dan       Damages                 1.83                                        1.83                                 
 Dan       sweeper                 1.83                                                  1.83
 Julie     Damages                 1.83                                        1.83
 Dan       Problem solve           1.83                            1.83
```

I think of pd.melt but it throws an error value var not present

```
res = pd.melt(result,id_vars = ['Function'],value_vars=['Total hours'])
```

Comment: Have you created 3 new columns or 4 ? `Damage processing, Problem solve, sweeper, Damages`

Comment: Sorry, i created four columns

Comment: are the columns really lowercase or is that a typo? Also how does User `Dan` becomes a `sweeper` in row 5? in the input it was `Damages`

Comment: Those are typo. sorry, Dan  will be damages on output too.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

here is a way using [`get_dummies`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.get_dummies.html) and [`df.assign`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.assign.html):

```
out = (df[['User','Function','Total hours']].assign(**pd.get_dummies(df['Function'])
       .mul(df['Total hours'],axis=0).replace(0,np.nan)))
print(out)
```

---

```
    User           Function  Total hours  Damage Processing  Damages  \
0  schae  Damage Processing         9.36               9.36      NaN   
1  Julie      Problem solve         9.70                NaN      NaN   
2   John            sweeper        18.90                NaN      NaN   
3    Dan            Damages         1.83                NaN     1.83   
4    Dan            Damages         1.83                NaN     1.83   
5  Julie            Damages         1.83                NaN     1.83   
6    Dan      Problem solve         1.83                NaN      NaN   

   Problem solve  sweeper  
0            NaN      NaN  
1           9.70      NaN  
2            NaN     18.9  
3            NaN      NaN  
4            NaN      NaN  
5            NaN      NaN  
6           1.83      NaN
```

Comment: This works as expected.Thanks. Is .mul is multiply? trying to understand how it worked

Comment: Yes exactly :) with axis 0 since we are multiplying on rows

Answer (score 0):

```py
for i in range(len(df)):
    col = df.loc[i]['Function']
    df.at[i, col] = df.xs(i)['Total hours']
    print(col)
```

Try this !
Variable `col` finds the column for which you want to insert the value of `Total hours`.